# .NET Core Hosting Bundle update requirements

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, windows-server

I'm currently trying to investigate what is required to update the .NET Core Hosting Bundle. We previously installed the 2.1.2 runtime and are looking to upgrade to LTS (we made it to production just before 2.1.3 was declared LTS). We successfully followed the steps in the [ASP.NET Core hosting installation docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#install-the-net-core-hosting-bundle) to get 2.1.2 installed e.g. `net stop was /y` and `net start w3svc`. However, there don't seem to be any instructions for what to do in the event of an update; do we need to once again run the `net stop/start` commands?  I did notice this tidbit in the docs, and wasn't sure if this would apply to updates on our servers.

> If the Windows Hosting Bundle installer detects that IIS requires a reset in order to complete installation, the installer resets IIS. If the installer triggers an IIS reset, all of the IIS app pools and websites are restarted.

Has anyone gone through this type of upgrade previously and able to provide some insights? We want to make sure there aren't any additional steps we need to take to ensure a full and proper install, but also don't want to perform unnecessary steps like `net stop was` if everything is good after the installer completes.

Comment: Before running the installer of the new version, move the server out of your load balancing cluster. Run the installer and Leave it to the installer to reset IIS. Once updated, move the server back and work on others. I assume that common sense as most users do anything (patching, app deployment) that way.

Comment: We know for fresh installs we need to pull it out of the load balancing cluster since it requires a `net stop was /y`, and for safety we planned to pull the server out with this update as well, seeing as it's common sense to make sure a server undergoing maintenance of any kind may be unable to service requests. My question is more of "what extra steps, if any, do we need to take to ensure a full and proper update?"